# how to get column name and field name at point in org-table

Tags: emacs, org-mode, spacemacs

table like this:

```
|  Time | ---AAA ---  | ---BBB ---  |
|-------+-------------+-------------+
|  9:45 |             |             |
| 10:00 |             |             |
| 10:15 |  i am here  |             |
| 10:30 |             |             |
| 10:45 |             |             |
|-------+-------------+-------------+
```

When I typed at line "i am here", is there any build-in functions to do this?

```
get-current-column-name(),return "AAA"
get-current-line-name(),return "10:15"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can not find any build-in function, so I write them, hope it helps

```
(defun dindom/org-table-get-current-colname()
  "get current column name if in org table"
  (if (org-table-p)
      (org-table-get 1 nil)
    (message "not in table!")
    )
  )

(defun dindom/org-table-get-current-linename()
  "get current line name if in org table"
  (if (org-table-p)
      (org-table-get nil 1)
    (message "not in table!")
    )
  )
```

or use org-table-get-field:

```
(defun dindom/org-table-get-current-linename()
  "get current line name if in org table"
  (if (org-table-p)
      (save-excursion
        (org-table-get-field 1)
        )
    (message "not in table!")
    )
  )
```

Comment: The second function should probably use `(org-table-get nil 1)` i.e. current line, column 1.  That makes it symmetrical and you avoid the save-excursion.

Comment: @Nick you are right, thanks! my code just want to show more build-in abilities to newbie like me.